# Cameras view problem – cameras maintenance

Tags: camera, maintenance

I did an install of a security camera setup for a client with about 150 cameras (indoors and outdoors).  The client is concerned that with this many cameras if anything happens to any of the cameras that impacts the view, they won’t have a way of knowing about it until a while later.  They are particularly concerned about things like tampering, or the maintenance crew accidentally moving a camera, or putting some furniture in front of it, or the lens getting scratched, etc.  Maybe some wear and tear but they are new cameras so it’s more about random things causing the view to be distorted rather than an actual problem with the cameras.

They are asking about an automated solution for the problem, if possible, otherwise, some active management services.  Has anyone here run into this issue or otherwise have a solution they can suggest?

Comment: What operating system? What software currently uses the cameras?

Comment: What is the price they are wiling to pay? What OS? Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.

Comment: 1. Windows operating system.  
2. All cameras are IP cameras and ONVIF-compliant (they have not settled on a Video Management Software platform, partly because of this issue).
3. Their budget is pretty open, they are looking for "bids" at the moment.  
4. Image verification only needs to happen a few times a day (up to once an hour).   No need for real-time processing (i.e., verify every video frame).

Is there a specific Video Management Platform you could recommend that has such functionality?  Or otherwise, some application that does this that interfaces with ONVIF cameras?